# How to resolve TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable on make_file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

On the last line, I am getting the subjected error. I am using Python 3.8.2 Shell for running the script.

```
f = open(fileFirst,'r').readlines
sf = open(fileSecond,'r').readlines
result = difflib.HtmlDiff()
diff = result.make_file(ff, sf, fileFirst, fileSecond)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing the method name `readlines` when you actually want to call it. So:

```
f = open(fileFirst,'r').readlines()
sf = open(fileSecond,'r').readlines()
result = difflib.HtmlDiff()
diff = result.make_file(ff, sf, fileFirst, fileSecond)
```

Note the parentheses.